# Copy array without redundancy

Tags: java

I have two arrays in my program. One is full(with redundant items in it). I want to copy all the items to the second empty array without redundancy. The only problem I have is "how to declare size of the second array?" Because Iam not sure how many are the redundant items in the first array.

Comment: Use Set. And convert back to array if you have to.

Comment: Could you explain more what 'redundancy' means? Just duplicates?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Java Set contains no duplicate elements, ArrayList is solution if array has duplicate elements

Comment: If by `redundancy` @Seshu means just duplicates then Set serves the purpose. As it wont allow to put duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert string array to list. Use a LinkedHashSet to eliminate duplicates. The LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order along with uniqueness.

Edit: I have removed the List as it is redundant.

```
    String[] words = {"ace", "ace","boom", "crew", "dog", "eon"}; 
    Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
    String[]  mywords=hs.toArray(new String[hs.size()]);
    for(int i=0;i<mywords.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("..."+mywords[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Without generics?Really in these days?And what about programming into interface, this code has a really poor design

Comment: @PetrMensik can u elaborate. You can edit my answer to correct the same. Talking about hashset type right?. I so edited my answer. Have a look

Comment: Right, you should use Set interface so you can switch implementation later.

Comment: I missed it. Thanks for pointing the mistake in code design and editing the same

Comment: Use of `List` is also redundant.

Comment: credits to Subir Kumar Sao and Petr Mensik for pointing the mistakes in code design

Answer (score 5):

I would use `Set` for this, that will remove duplicates from your array and you convert then back to array or another collection of you need that.

```
Set<Item> withoutDups = new HashSet<Item>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
//now you have it without duplicates and do whatevet you want with it:-)
Item[] arrayWithoutDups = new Item[withoutDups.size()];
withoutDups.toArray(arrayWithoutDups); // fill the array
```

Comment: The `= new Item[withoutDups.size()];` is unnecessary, since you're immediately assigning `arrayWithoutDups` to something else in the next line.

Comment: +1 for the answer and thanks for pointing the mistake in my code design.

Comment: @PetrMensik I updated you answer if you don't mind :) .. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays` are of fixed size. You should use `ArrayList` in this case.

However, if you have to use an array then you should allocate the size of 2nd array equal to the size of 1st array because it may contain no redundant elements at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ArrayList` which size can be smaller than original array, then create array from it, if needed.

Comment: A Set Implementation is a better choice if he is using a collection.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao It depends of SO definition of 'redundancy'

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem ?
Loop through values in source array, find number of redundant items. Then allocate second array and in next loop copy values.

Complexity of this approach is `2n=O(n)`

Comment: yea but looking for a better approach

Comment: Then put this condition into your question. We can't read your thoughts :)

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't know which item are redundant you need to loop over your array. I suggest that you use temporary List uniqueItemsList to add the items during your loop.
The list will grow as needed.

Then you can get a array with code like this (replace String with your type) :

```
String uniqueItems[] = new String[uniqueItemsList.size()]; 
uniqueItems = uniqueItemsList.toArray(uniqueItems);
```